# Upgraded to 10.9, but it broke my Windows 8.1 Boot Camp partition!

Tags: bootcamp, startup, macos, windows

I just got Windows 8.1 set up via Boot Camp a couple days ago, and everything was working wonderfully.

Today, I upgraded my Mac to OSX v10.9, as suggested by Apple. Nobody told me it would break my Boot Camp system!

First, my Windows partition didn't even show up in the option-menu at boot, so I tried following the instructions [here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4144252?start=0&tstart=0), which fixed the option-menu, but the system still won't load!

When I tried to boot into Windows, it says it can't find the operating system! So somehow it seems that the 10.9 update is incompatible with previously-existing Boot Camp partitions.

What can I do? I need my Windows partition for work!

Answer (score 1):

You could try to fix the MBR Table.

I would recommend by using a Linux LiveCD or the rEFInd CD http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/index.html

Alternatively, rEFInd can be installed on OS X so you also get a Partition Manager Tool. I used this tool once to fix my broken MBR Table.

You can find the install instructions for OS X here: [rEFInd Install OS X](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/installing.html#installsh)

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I have heard of this issue before.

I fixed it with the windows 8.1 boot disc. Doing a system restore inside 8.1
I first modified the booting with http://refit.sourceforge.net/

Then I was able to boot to disc and detect the windows 8.1 partition.

Comment: Could you elaborate on this with some steps involving the use of rEFIt. That software is not for the feint of hearted and can cause more problems if you don't know what you're doing than it's worth.